# Bounding a random variable $X$ by $\Bbb{E}(X^4)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable. Is there a way to bound the probability that $|X|$ is large in terms of $\Bbb{E}(X^{4})$?

Comment: Do you mean something like $\mathbb{P}(|X|>M) < \alpha \mathbb{E}(X^4)$, for some $M$ and $\alpha$?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Extended_version_for_monotonically_increasing_functions) (extended version), for any $a > 0$ we have:

$$\Bbb{P}(|X| \ge a) \le \dfrac{\Bbb{E}(X^4)}{a^4}$$

Hope it helps.